# Are these two Ruby methods with a hash parameter equivalent? If not, why not?

Tags: ruby

First version of the method:

```
def method(param1, param2={})
  meth_x(param2).meth_y(param1)
  meth_z
  #...
end
```

Second version of the method (notice the second param2)...

```
def method(param1, param2={})
  meth_x(param2={}).meth_y(param1)
  meth_z
  #...
end
```

I would assume that these two methods are equivalent and thus I'd go with the first one (less typing, less redundancy).

However, I'm curious if these would be expected to behave differently and, if so, why.

Comment: Is there a reason why you think they might behave differently?

Comment: I'm getting vague claims from other developers on my team about differences in behavior--though at the moment I'm skeptical about them. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second, you set the `param2` to an empty hash before giving it as a parameter to `meth_x`. In the method definition the `param2 = {}` means that if the parameter is omitted, then it is set to this default empty hash, but in the `meth_x(param2 = {})` means that you drop the original content of param2 and replace it with an empty hash, then giving it to `meth_x`.

```
irb(main):001:0> a = {:alma => 2}
=> {:alma=>2}
irb(main):002:0> puts a
{:alma=>2}
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts(a)
{:alma=>2}
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> puts(a = {})
{}
=> nil
```

Comment: So in the second instance param2 will *always* be an empty hash?

Comment: I mean, *effectively* it will always be an empty hash, regardless of what gets passed to #method?

Comment: Yepp, thats the way. Even better, for the rest of the `method` `param2` will contain this new value. If you mean to initialize it to an empty hash in case it is `nil`, then use `meth_x(param2 ||= {})` or `meth_x(param2 || {})`. This way the original content won't be lost. But since you are using default parameter value in the method definition, it can not be the case.